# Complex selecting in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The dataset below indicates which products are active for each customer, and in what month.
Month can take several values (1,2,3,...etc), there are many products (x,y,z,etc), and product_active is binary to indicate active status.

```
cust_id month product  product_active
1234    1     x        1 
1234    2     x        0 
1234    1     y        0 
1234    2     y        1
```

How would I select all customers who have switched from product x to product y, from month 1 to month 2? I would like to generalise this, i.e. be able to select all customers who switched from product a to product b, from month m1 to month m2.

Comment: Can you post more data? In the data you have put now, the one customer switched from 1 to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there may be a more pythonic way to do this using a `.groupby()` and vector solution, but here is a solution that will provide a df with the results you are looking for.  I am making an assumption on your data that your product active column doesn't matter.

```
#DF Setup
_______________________
col = ['cust_id', 'month', 'product',  'product_active']
data = [
(1234,    1,     'x',        1 ),
(1234,    2,     'x',        0 ),
(1235,    1,     'y',        0 ),
(1235,    2,     'y',        1 ),
(1236,    1,     'x',        1 ),
(1236,    2,     'y',        0 )]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)
```

Added an additional customer (1236) to simulate product change (x->y) from m1 to m2.

```
#Solution
______________________
result_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if i == 0:
        pass
    elif df.loc[i-1,'cust_id'] == df.loc[i,'cust_id']:
        if (df.loc[i-1,'month'] == 1) & (df.loc[i,'month'] == 2):
            if (df.loc[i-1,'product'] == 'x') & (df.loc[i,'product'] == 'y'):
                result_df = result_df.append(df.loc[i])
```

Here is the generic solution wrapped in a function:

```
def filter_function(month,p1,p2):
    '''
    month - month you wish to check for product change.
    p1 - "From" product
    p2 - "To" product
    '''
    result_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        if i == 0:
            pass
        elif df.loc[i-1,'cust_id'] == df.loc[i,'cust_id']:
            if (df.loc[i-1,'month'] == month-1) & (df.loc[i,'month'] == month):
                if (df.loc[i-1,'product'] == p1) & (df.loc[i,'product'] == p2):
                    result_df = result_df.append(df.loc[i])
    return result_df

filter_function(2,'x','y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you

```
mask = df['product_active'].ne(df['product_active'].shift(2))
a = df[~mask & df.product_active==1]['cust_id']
Cust_not_switching = list(set(df[df['cust_id'].isin(a)]['cust_id'].to_list()))
Cust_switching = list(set(df[~df['cust_id'].isin(a)]['cust_id'].to_list()))
```

**Input**

```
cust_id     month   product     product_active
0   1234    1   x   1
1   1234    2   x   0
2   1234    1   y   0
3   1234    2   y   1
4   1235    1   x   1
5   1235    2   x   1
6   1235    1   y   0
7   1235    2   y   0
8   1236    1   x   0
9   1236    2   x   1
10  1236    1   y   1
11  1236    2   y   0
```

**Output**

```
Cust_not_switching = [1235]
Cust_switching = [1234, 1236]
```

This will work only if there are 2 products.

Comment: Hi, what is mask?

Comment: Sorry, i had missed that line of the code. I have added it now.